# How do i append an object call with a variable JS

Tags: javascript, json

So the problem, i have data that i call by using window.blah.blah and it will spit out info based on a user or an item in a database.

Now my problem is that i want to use the window.blah.blah with a dynamic appendage so like window.blah.blah.VARIABLE1

i have tried window.blah.blah.instances[variable] but i get a typeerror saying the value of variable is not defined (so if variable = test1 the error would be TypeError: Cannot read property 'test1' of undefined. variable is generated so it can be test1 test2 that correspond to stored objects.

if it helps i am using the call within a loop that is using it to get access a stored json obj with different object names.

also if I one of the objects is called test1 and i do window.blah.blah.test1 it accesses the object but window.blah.blah.instances[test1] gets the above error.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: wow i feel dumb, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the syntax you are looking for is `window.blah.blah[VARIABLE1]`
(assuming the blahs are objects.)

note that storing data on window is typically a bad idea, so for the following example, I'll move the top-level object from the global space (accessed through `window`) into a local variable:

```
var myObj = {
    blah: {
        blah: {}
    }
};
var fooVar == 'foo';

function getMyDynamicVariable() {
    return "foo"; //really this would by some dynamically generated string
}

//example usage:

myObj.blah.blah[getMyDynamicVariable()];

// OR

myObj.blah.blah[fooVar];

// would be the same as

myObj.blah.blah.foo //(in this exact example, where all functions and variables contain the string 'foo'.)
```